# What ProgressDialog's getContext is not what I pass into

Tags: android

```
public AsyncSyncWithCloud(HistoryFragmentActivity historyFragmentActivity) {
    this.historyFragmentActivity = historyFragmentActivity;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(historyFragmentActivity);

    // ???
    // java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to xxx.charting.HistoryFragmentActivity
    HistoryFragmentActivity test = ((HistoryFragmentActivity)progressDialog.getContext());
}
```

I was wondering, why I pass in my own `Activity` as context to `ProgressDialog`. When I perform `getContext` from progressDialog, I do not get what I passed in previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is good solution

```
    private HistoryFragmentActivity getHistoryFragmentActivity(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        return (HistoryFragmentActivity)(((android.content.ContextWrapper)progressDialog.getContext()).getBaseContext());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you found, the context has been wrapped.

If you drill down, you will find in the constructor:-

```
    Dialog(Context context, int theme, boolean createContextThemeWrapper) {
    if (createContextThemeWrapper) {
        if (theme == 0) {
            TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
            context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(com.android.internal.R.attr.dialogTheme,
                    outValue, true);
            theme = outValue.resourceId;
        }
        mContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, theme);
    } else {
        mContext = context;
    }

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Window w = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);
    mWindow = w;
    w.setCallback(this);
    w.setOnWindowDismissedCallback(this);
    w.setWindowManager(mWindowManager, null, null);
    w.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    mListenersHandler = new ListenersHandler(this);
}
```

which wraps the context when there's no theme currently set.

While you *can* cast it as you are doing, I am not sure how reliable it will be - you can put instanceof checks around it, but it may be that you need to look at the whole thing from a fresh angle.

Usually, the best way to get the activity from a fragment is by using getActivity() and casting that instead. Better again is to attach a listener onAttach() approach:

```
Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        listener = (Listener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(TAG
                + " must implement Listener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    listener = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```